# PostGIS, st_within, and a join

Tags: postgis, sql, attribute-joins

So I'm in the middle of learning PostGIS/PostgreSQL.

I've a polygon table ans I've a point table. The polygon layer contains a foreign key that points to another table. For the example the Foreign key points to the type of polygon. So TypeFK in the polygon table  references TypeID in the type_tbl;

I can do a:

```
select type 
from polygon as a, type_tbl as b 
where a.typefk = b.typeid;
```

Now I know the polygon is a type of tree.

I can do a:

```
select typefk 
from polygon 
join points on ST_Contains(polygon.geom, points.geom);
```

I know what typefk they fall in.

I'm ultimately trying to return the type of polygon the points are located within.

So - gurus of PostGIS/SQL - how do I combine the two?

I've been sitting here too long without a break unfortunately and am just not getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  I might have the column and tables wrong and not sure what fields you want returned

```
SELECT t.type, point.gid As ptgid, polygon.gid As polygid
 FROM polygon INNER JOIN type_tbl As t ON polygon.typefk = t.typeid
INNER JOIN points ON ST_Contains(polygon.geom, points.geom);
```